# WCF (svcutil) creating async methods automatically

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf, asynchronous, wcf-binding

WCF (svcutil) creating async methods automatically, how to prevent this? I am testing it with WCF Test Client. I tried changing config but no luck.

```
<endpoint address="Service.svc" binding="wsHttpBinding" name="wsHttpBinding_Service" behaviorConfiguration="Behaviour_FO" bindingConfiguration="wsHttpBinding_ServiceConfig" contract="Service.IService">
<identity>
<dns value="localhost" />
</identity>
<baseAddresses><add baseAddress="http://del1-lhp-n67557/Service/Service.svc" /> </baseAddress>
```

where del1-lhp-n67557 is my hostname.

Comment: How exactly are you running svcutil? because according to [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/servicemodel-metadata-utility-tool-svcutil-exe) the default is sync only, and to generate async methods requires the `/async` / `/a` flag - in which case... don't supply that?

Comment: The implementation of an asynchronous method requires a method call. If you don't want to use an asynchronous method, you can comment out the called method. Also refer to [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/how-to-implement-an-asynchronous-service-operation) if you are not sure what kind of asynchronous invocation it is.